# Python IZIP list comprehension returns empty list

Tags: python, izip

I have a list of strings that I am sorting. There are 12 different key strings within the list that I am using to sort by. So instead of writing 12 separate list comprehensions I would like to use a list of empty lists and a list of key strings to sort, then use izip to perform list comprehensions. Here is what I am doing:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> tran_types = ['DDA Debit', 'DDA Credit']
>>> tran_list = [[] for item in tran_types]
>>> trans = get_info_for_branch('sco_monday.txt',RT_NUMBER)
>>> for x,y in izip(tran_list, TRANSACTION_TYPES):
    x = [[item.strip() for item in line.split('    ') if not item == ''] for line in trans if y in line]
>>> tran_list[0]
[]
```

I would like to see an output more like the following:

```
>>> tran_list[0]
[['DDA Debit','0120','18','3','83.33'],['DDA Debit','0120','9','1','88.88']]
```

The output doesn't make sense to me; the objects that izip returns are lists and strings

```
>>> for x,y in itertools.izip(tran_list, TRANSACTION_TYPES):
type(x), type(y)
(<type 'list'>, <type 'str'>)
(<type 'list'>, <type 'str'>)
```

Why is this process returning empty lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A variable is much like a sticker.**

You can have multiple stickers placed on the same thing:

```
>>> a=b=[]       #put stickers a and b on the empty list
>>> a.append(1)  #append one element to the (previously) empty list
>>> b            #what's the value of the object the b sticker is attached to?
[1]
```

And can have things that have no sticker at all:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> a=""         #[1,2,3] still exists
```

Although they're not very useful, since you can't refer to them - so they are eventually [garbage collected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29).

---

```
>>> for x,y in izip(tran_list, TRANSACTION_TYPES):
    x = [[item.strip() for item in line.split('    ') if not item == ''] for line in trans if y in line]
```

Here, you have a sticker with a `x` in it. When you assign (`x=...`), you're changing the placement of the sticker - not modifying the place where the sticker originally was placed on.

You're assigning to a variable that is, in turn, assigned each time the for loop cycles. 
**Your assignment has absolutely no effect.**

This is true for any kind of for loop in python, and bears no connection to `izip` in particular.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to stuff the variable x back into tran_list after it's been zipped, but izip only guarantees that the returned type is an iterator, not that it's a strict pointer back to the original list. You may be losing all the work you're doing inside the for loop without realizing it.